# DrawerLayout принимает только ListView?

Tags: xml, android-sdk, android, java

Навигация слева возможна только в виде **80%-го** высунутого окна с **ListView-ом**, или можно как-то создать отдельный **Activity** и его выдвигать, а на нем кнопки,поля и т.д

Смотрел кучу примеров, понимаю так что только **ListView** туда засунуть можно(

Comment: меняйте `ListView` на угодную Вам разметку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас  в корне не верное понимание ─ не Activity а Fragment, потратьте часик, почитайте про фрагменты это Вам даст больше чем  плюшки боковой навигации.
По вашему вопросу ─ не обязательно список. боковое меню это фрагмент, ставьте туда что хотите, задавайте ему любую ширину